# problema ao mostrar categoria wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou desenvolvendo um tema para `Wordpress` meu menu é gerado da seguinte forma em `header.php`

```
<li><a href="<?php echo get_option('home');?>">Início</a></li>
     <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&orderby=id'); ?>
     <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&order=id'); ?>
```

O problema é que quando acesso uma categoria ao tentar mostrar os posts ele retorna todos os posts e não os referentes a categoria.

category.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolvi o problema faltava o `wp_reset_query();` ao final do `header.php`

Answer (score 1):

Faz assim:

```
<?php
   query_posts("category_name=SUA_CATEGORIA");
   while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: o problema é que não é apenas uma categoria!

Comment: Já tentou usar o is_category()? Ai você passa sua categoria, faz um if, não sei como quer fazer.

Comment: Tente dar mais explicações sobre sua solução, para que também seja útil a futuros visitantes